# Azure SQL DB and SQL MI Security Concerns

Tags: security, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-managed-instance

I have 7 different SQL Managed Instances, which were newly migrated over from SQL VM. I also have 7 different Azure SQL Databases, which were also newly created.

I want to make sure that I completely secure all my MI and Azure SQL Databases to eliminate security vulnerabilities and also to avoid any SQL injection attacks.

I have already implemented the following:

Public Endpoint is enabled and I have setup NSG rules to configure the IP addresses which have inbound access to the SQL MI instances.

I was also doing some reading into some other best practices to secure the SQL Managed Instance and Azure SQL Databases and below are some of the things that I found:

1. Implement Row level security
2. SQL Database Auditing
3. Always Encrypted feature
4. Dynamic Data Masking
5. Data Discovery and Classification

I would appreciate if you can advise if these are worth looking into and should they be implemented in the environments based on your experience.

Also does implementing any of these best practices degrade performance.